# Cannot log into ExpressionEngine After Deleting Member From Database

Tags: php, mysql, expressionengine

I had a problem with new member spam in an ExpressionEngine Site. Over a couple days, I amassed 20k members. I disabled new member registration but I still had to get rid of all the extraneous members. I ran an SQL statement to delete all members who had never made a comment or a forum post but I didn't realize that the admin member that I use was also deleted. Now I can't log in to fix the problem.

Even stranger, an account which I know that I did not delete can also not log in anymore.

Does anyone have suggestions to help me log in?

edit: using ee v 1.6.1

Comment: can any other of the 20k members log in ? or is this a case , where you need to log in , to fill out a bug report .. also , any decent site will have a DB backup. Just restore admin users from that.

Comment: yes, good to make a snapshot before doing a mass-delete. in case things turn out wrong.

Comment: I know this doesn't help you now, but it's always a good idea to make a backup of your database when making drastic changes like that. You could possibly try creating a fresh install somewhere new, find the admin row, and copy that info over to your site.

Comment: Thanks. I actually did make a backup of the database in case of this exact problem but I didn't notice that the dump failed after 44k lines, just as the members table data was dumping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evan - if you can access your database directly, via phpMyAdmin or otherwise, just create a new member directly without a password, then use the password reset function (link found on the EE login screen) to have a new one generated and sent to you.

Just enter values for `username`, `screen_name`, and `email_address`, and set the `group_id` to `1`.

Comment: This worked great to get a new user created, but I cant log in (usefully). If I type the wrong password I return to the login screen with an error message, but if I type the correct password I return to the login screen without an error message. Any ideas?

Comment: The unique_id field had to be populated as well. It doesnt seem to matter what with, but I could not log in until I wrote something in the unique_id field in exp_members. Now I can log in. Thanks for the help.